# in python, how to make main args global

Tags: python, global-variables, argparse

I want to access the args values in a class function in python.
For example, I wrote a sample test program below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse

class Weather(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0.0
    def run(self):
        print('in weather.run')
        if (args.sunny == True):
            print('It\'s Sunny')
        else:
            print('It\'s Not Sunny')

def main():
    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__)
    argparser.add_argument(
        '--sunny', action='store_true', dest='sunny', help='set if you want sunny weather')
    args = argparser.parse_args()

    print('args.sunny = ', args.sunny)

    weather = Weather()


    weather.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run it(./test.py), I get errors below.

```
('args.sunny = ', False)
in weather.run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "./test.py", line 27, in main
    weather.run()
  File "./test.py", line 10, in run
    if (args.sunny == True):
NameError: global name 'args' is not defined
```

I tried putting 'global args' in the Weather.run function but got the same error. What is the correct method?

Comment: better send it as argument - `Weather(args)` or `weather.run(args)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set it global by:

```
global args
args = argparser.parse_args()
```

or just pass sunny as argument to weather:

```
def run(self, sunny):
.....

weather.run(self, args.sunny)
```

Comment: thanks, just one thing. 'global args' should come before assigning to args.

Comment: Thanks @ChanKim. I forgot this detail

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you add whatever is in main() into the if statement?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse

class Weather(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0.0
    def run(self):
        print('in weather.run')
        if (args.sunny == True):
            print('It\'s Sunny')
        else:
            print('It\'s Not Sunny')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__)
    argparser.add_argument(
        '--sunny', action='store_true', dest='sunny', help='set if you want sunny weather')
    args = argparser.parse_args()

    print('args.sunny = ', args.sunny)

    weather = Weather()


    weather.run()
```

Comment: Oh, I see. variables defined in main are global. In my code, main() is not the so-called main program.  Your answer is almost close but..  what if I want to access the variable 'args' that were defined in the function 'main()' ?

Comment: My original question was wrong. The 'args' was not defined in the real 'main' body.. Ramon's answer shows me how to make a variable defined in a function global.  I don't know what to select as the correct answer..:)

Answer (score 1):

The two answers provided didn't match my app's design, this worked for me though:

```
class Weather(object):
    def run(self):
        if (args.sunny == True):
            print('It\'s Sunny')
        else:
            print('It\'s Not Sunny')

def main():
    global args
    args = argparser.parse_args()
```